# why sh softlink to bash doesn't work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

we use [unix modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) and have `sh` softlinked to `bash` in system.

```
$ ls -al /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 27  2016 /bin/sh -> bash
```

I thought it should be the same use `#!/bin/sh` & `#!/bin/bash`, but it is different.

For example, we have `bash_completion` script

```
$ cat bash_completion
_module_not_yet_loaded() {
    comm -23  <(_module_avail|sort)  <(tr : '\n' <<<${LOADEDMODULES}|sort)
}
```

I try to initialize this

```
$ bash
$ source bash_completion
$ sh  # switch to sh 
$ source bash_completion
sh: bash_completion: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: bash_completion: line 3: `  comm -23  <(_module_avail|sort)  <(tr : '\n' <<<${LOADEDMODULES}|sort)'
```

So what's the problem ? why `sh` softlink to `bash` doesn't work as I expected ?

Comment: Bash detects that it has been invoked as `sh` and enables sh-compatibility.

Comment: It is important not to put bash-constructs into a `#!/bin/sh` file. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/what-does-it-mean-to-be-sh-compatible).

Comment: Thank for quick answer. Can u explain more ? and give some mode code sample in answer directly so I can accept later

Comment: There's an existing question with answers that cover this ground rather comprehensively -- see the link up at the top of the question.

Comment: Item 29 at [Bash manual — POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode); process substitution is not available.  Don't use `sh` if you want to use `<(…)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank, I just can't find the question in google/sto directly.